# Unable to understand why this Python FOR loop isn't working as intended

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm trying to generate a random dataset to plot a graph in Python 2.7.

In which the 'y' list stores 14 integers between 100 and 135. I did that using the following code:

```
y = [random.randint(100, 135) for i in xrange(14)]
```

And for the 'x' list, I wanted to store the index values of the elements in 'y'. To achieve this, I tried using the code:

```
x = []

for i in y:

   pt = y.index(i)

   x.append(pt)
```

But when I run this, the result of the for loop ends up being:

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9, 1, 11, 12, 13]
```

Why isn't the result the following?

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Because `y` has duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.index()` finds the index of the *first* occurrence of that object in the `list`, which produces the results you saw when the `list` has repeated elements. Something like `[1, 1, 1].index(1)` would produce `0`.

If you want to generate a list of indices, you can use `list(range(len(y)))`, which finds the length of `y`, creates a `range()` object out of it, then creates a `list` out of that object. Since you're using Python 2, you can omit the `list()` call, since Python 2's `range()` will already return a `list`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explains why, and how to get about it doing the right way. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Python is returning the *first* location of a value in y.

Running your code, here's an example `y`:

```
[127, 124, 105, 119, 121, 118, 130, 123, 122, 105, 110, 109, 108, 110]
```

110 is at both 10 and 13. 105 is at both 2 and 9. Python stops looking after it finds the first one, so `x` then becomes:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 10, 11, 12, 10]
```